# Graph theory (number of walks in the graph)

Tags: graph-theory

Given a simple graph $G$ with adjacency matrix $A$, let $G'$ be the same graph as $G$ but with a self-loop added at each vertex $v$. Let $S$ be the adjacency matrix of the graph $G'$, i.e., $S=A+I$.

(a) If $X=S^n$, prove that $x_{ij}>0$ if and only if there exists a walk of length at most $n$ from a vertex $i$ to a
 vertex $j$ in $G$.

(b) If $X=S^n$, is it true that $x_{ij}$ is precisely the number of walks
 of lenth at most $n$ from vertex $i$ to vertex $j$ in graph $G$? Either
 prove that is it true or construct a counter-example.

Comment: If you prove that $A^n(i,j)$ contains the number of walks from $i$ to $j$ of length $n$ regarding graph $G$, both questions can be solved quite quickly.

Answer (score 1):

Let's assume the following property: $A^n(i,j)$ represents the number of walks from $i$ to $j$ in the graph G.

Then, because $A$ and $I$ commute, we have :

$$ X = S^n = (A+I)^n = \sum_{k=0}^n \binom{n}{k}A^k$$.

$\underline{Question \text{ }(a)}$

$$X(i,j) > 0 \Leftrightarrow \exists k \in [|0,n|]/ A^k(i,j)>0 $$

$$ \Leftrightarrow \text{There is a path of length at most n between } i \text{ and } j \text{ in } G.$$

$\underline{Question \text{ }(b)}$

False. Consider G=({1,2}, {(1,2)}).

Then $S^2(1,2)=2$ but there is only one path from $1$ to $2$.